# Cannot convert value of type 'Result' to expected argument type 'EmailContentData'

Tags: ios, swift, types, casting, type-conversion

```
enum Result {
case success(r: EmailContentData)
case failure(e: Error)}


static func getMessageList(index : Int, pageCount: Int, completion : @escaping (EmailContentData) -> ())
{
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async
        {
            let apiString : String = String(index) + "/" + String(pageCount)
            var objEmailContentData : EmailContentData? = EmailContentData.init(fromDictionary: NSDictionary())

            ApiHelper.sharedSession.post(Constant.API.messagelistApi + apiString, postData: NSDictionary(), methodtype: Constant.API.httpGet) { (isError, data, errorDescription) in
                guard let data = data else { return }
                do {
                    let result = EmailContentData.init(fromDictionary: data.value(forKey:"data") as! NSDictionary)
                    completion(Result.success(r: result))
                } catch let error {
                    completion(Result.failure(e: error))
                }
            }
    }
}
```

I am getting  error in success "Cannot convert value of type 'Result' to expected argument type 'EmailContentData'" 
and similar for completion error "Cannot convert value of type 'Result' to expected argument type 'EmailContentData'"

Please anyone suggest me what I am doing wrong? Thank in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@escaping (Result) -> ()` instead of @escaping `(EmailContentData) -> ()`

```
static func getMessageList(index : Int, pageCount: Int, completion : @escaping (Result) -> ())
{
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async
        {
            let apiString : String = String(index) + "/" + String(pageCount)
            var objEmailContentData : EmailContentData? = EmailContentData.init(fromDictionary: NSDictionary())

            ApiHelper.sharedSession.post(Constant.API.messagelistApi + apiString, postData: NSDictionary(), methodtype: Constant.API.httpGet) { (isError, data, errorDescription) in
                guard let data = data else { return }
                do {
                    let result = EmailContentData.init(fromDictionary: data.value(forKey:"data") as! NSDictionary)
                    completion(Result.success(r: result))
                } catch let error {
                    completion(Result.failure(e: error))
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: catch let error {
                        completion(Result.failure(e: error))
                    }

'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block